# FlexImages Justified grid image size on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using FlexImages jquery plugin for Justified grid. It works great. Only issue i have is i want the images to be 100% width on mobile (view port 550px or less)

jQuery Fleximage plugin: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/flex-images/demo.html

Code:

```
<div style="max-width:908px;margin:auto;padding:0 10px 10px">
    <div id="demo1" class="flex-images">
        <div class="item" data-w="219" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/219x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="279" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/279x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="270" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/270x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="270" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/270x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="147" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/147x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="276" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/276x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="319" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/319x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="270" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/270x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="290" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/290x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="305" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/305x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="240" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/240x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="270" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/270x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="283" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/283x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="271" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/271x180.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item" data-w="258" data-h="180"><img src="http://placehold.it/258x180.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#demo1').flexImages({rowHeight: 160});
```

i created a jsfiddle and you can see it from below link

https://jsfiddle.net/1kgs3soc/

I try adding below css but no luck.

```
@media (max-width:550px) {
.flex-images > div.item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

I tried all the css tricks that i can think of but nothing helped. Can any one point me out how to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .flex-images .item {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .flex-images .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

try using this media query

Comment: thanks it work but there there is a height issue. Tried adding height: auto to the div but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this,

```
@media (max-width:550px) {
.flex-images > div.item {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.flex-images > div.item img {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks it work but is solution also have a height issue.

Comment: If you want an image to be specific height. Then, give a specific height to the parent container or `div` i.e. `.flex-images > div.item`. so according to the height and width of the parent one, the image will fit inside.